Vuejs 2 & tinymce not working when importing from node_modules
I'm using tinymce editor and I'm trying to create a RichTextBox component in my vuejs2 project.
I'm having an issue however that the imports that tinymce requires are not working when trying to import them form node_modules. I had to create a tinymce directory in my public directory in the project and copy the: (icons, models, plugins, skins, themes) directories from the node_modules.
I tried aliasing the tinymce path in my vue.config.js but it did nothing.:
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'tinymce': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/tinymce')
      }
    }
  }

Here is my component:
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import tinymce from 'tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme';
import 'tinymce/icons/default/icons';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';

export default {
  name: 'RichTextBox',
  mounted() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#editor',
      plugins: ' link table',
      skin_url: '/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide',
      content_css: '/tinymce/skins/content/default',
      base_url: '/tinymce',
      promotion: false,
      paste_as_text: true,
      toolbar:
          'selectall table cut copy paste' +
          '| undo redo' +
          '| formatselect bold italic underline strikethrough sub sup ' +
          '| alignleft aligncenter alignright | alignjustify' +
          '| bullist numlist outdent indent ' +
          '| link unlink',
      table_toolbar:
          'tableprops tabledelete ' +
          '| tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow ' +
          '| tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol',
      entity_encoding: 'numeric',
      menubar: ''
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    const editor = tinymce.get('editor');
    if (editor) {
      editor.remove();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>


The error I get when trying to import from node_modules is:
Unexpected token '<' model.js
EDIT:
package.json:
 "tinymce": "^7.1.1",
 "vue": "^2.6.14"


Do you have a model.js somewhere?

model.js is inside the node_modules/tinymce/models

Give a try to this one maybe. Also, you probably gonna need to use the v4 of TinyMCE or something similar (and old) because you want to make it work with Vue2 and Webpack. I don't expect it to work with the latest v7.

Thanks that did not work unfortunately. However I have found an answer here:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/issues/403#issuecomment-1898613308

Thanks for reporting a solution for further readers! I've posted an answer even if you found the solution, hope it's fine.

OP achieved to have a working solution from this Github issue.
This kind of setup is currently necessary
<script setup>
import 'tinymce'
import Editor from "@tinymce/tinymce-vue"

/* Required TinyMCE components */
import 'tinymce/icons/default/icons.min.js';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js';
import 'tinymce/models/dom/model.min.js';

/* Import a skin (can be a custom skin instead of the default) */
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.js';

/* Import plugins */
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist';
import 'tinymce/plugins/code';
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons';
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';

/* content UI CSS is required */
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.js';

/* The default content CSS can be changed or replaced with appropriate CSS for the editor content. */
import 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.js';
</script>

